ErrorMessage se muestra al montar el componte cuando uso useFieldArray - veeValidate - Yup
Estoy haciendo un pequeño formulario para validar el ingreso de direcciones:
<div v-for="(data, index) in valueFields" :key="index" class="alignItemsForm mb-8">
                <div class="col-span-1 flex-col md:col-span-5">
                    <label-required :for="`ub${index}`" label="Ubigeo" :mark="true"/>
                    <InputText v-model="data.value.ubigeo" :id="`ub${index}`" :name="`ubigeo[${index}]`" size="small"
                               :invalid="!!errors[`address[${index}].ubigeo`]" @blur="validateField(`address[${index}].ubigeo`)"/>
                    <span class="markRequired">{{ errors[`address[${index}].ubigeo`] }}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-span-1 flex-col md:col-span-5">
                    <label-required :for="`loca${index}`" label="Dirección" :mark="true"/>
                    <InputText v-model="data.value.location" :id="`loca${index}`" :name="`location[${index}]`" size="small"
                               :invalid="!!errors[`address[${index}].location`]" @blur="validateField(`address[${index}].location`)"/>
                    <span class="markRequired">{{ errors[`address[${index}].location`] }}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-span-1 flex-col md:col-span-2 flex items-center justify-center">
                    <Button label="Remove" @click="removeAddress(index)"/>
                </div>
            </div>

Y este apartado es para validar mis entradas:
const schemaValidate = ref(yup.object().shape({
    address: yup.array().of(
        yup.object().shape({
            location: yup.string().required("Ingrese una dirección").label("location"),
            ubigeo: yup.string().required("Seleccione un ubigeo").label("ubigeo")
        })
    ).required("Ingrese al menos una dirección").label("Dirección")
}));

const { handleSubmit, resetForm, errors, validateField } = useForm({
    validationSchema: schemaValidate, initialValues: fields, validateOnMount: false
});

const { fields: valueFields, push: addDirection, remove: removeAddress } = useFieldArray("address");

Ahora como bien se describe en el titulo, los errores se muestran al momento de montar mi formulario, mas no cuando envie este o cuando use la funcion validateField
¿Quiza deba de agregar alguna validacion mas o algo?
